# How to install PyQt4 for Python 3.6 in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt4, python-3.6

I have tried to install it using SIP but in windows make is not working. So I am stuck in installation.

Comment: Care to share some things? Like errors you see, actual steps you took? or are we supposed to do some kind of divination?

Comment: I have tried the installation method that is provided on [link](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) But it won't work for me.

Comment: I have tried installing the binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4 for python 3.5 and 3.6 both. Still it is not working. Now it throws DLL error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing the binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4

Make sure you choose the right 32 or 64 bits version.

Comment: `PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` it throws this error

Comment: Are you sure you have python 3.6 64 bits?

Comment: builtins.ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.   It throws this error now.